My first arObject hide when tracking second imageTarget
I am developing a Flutter application with the Vuforia SDK engine, but I have an issue:
Why, when I track ImageTarget2 after ImageTarget1, does my first object, which is associated with ImageTarget1, hide, and the second object, which is associated with ImageTarget2, render? I want both objects to remain in the scene.
Here is my shader which is a rectangle :
GLuint
GLESRenderer::createRectangleShader() {
//    const char* vertexShaderSource =
//            "attribute vec4 a_Position;\n"
//            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;\n"
//            "void main() {\n"
//            "  gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;\n"
//            "}\n";

    // 1. Vertex Shader Source
    const char* vertexShaderSource =
            "attribute vec4 a_Position;\n"
            "attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;\n" // Add this line for texture coordinates
            "varying vec2 v_TexCoord;\n"
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
            "  gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;\n"
            "  v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;\n" // Pass texture coordinates to fragment shader
            "}\n";

    // 2. Fragment Shader Source
    const char* fragmentShaderSource =
            "precision mediump float;\n"
            "varying vec2 v_TexCoord;\n"
//            "uniform vec4 u_Color;\n"
            "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
//            "  gl_FragColor = u_Color;\n"
              "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoord);"
            "}\n";

    // 3. Create Shaders
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // 4. Compile Shaders
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // 5. Create Program and Link Shaders
    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(programID);
    // Check for linking errors (add error handling here)

    // 6. Delete Shaders (they are no longer needed)
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    return programID;
}

renderRectangle method:
void
GLESRenderer::renderRectangle(const VuMatrix44F& projectionMatrix, const VuMatrix44F& modelViewMatrix, GLuint textureId) {
    // 1. Define Rectangle Vertices
    static const GLfloat rectVertices[] = {
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Bottom left
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Bottom right
            -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, // Top left
            0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // Top right
    };

    // Define Texture Coordinates
    static const GLfloat textureCoords[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom left
            1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom right
            0.0f, 1.0f, // Top left
            1.0f, 1.0f  // Top right
    };

    // 2. Create Shader Program (if not already created)
    GLuint shaderProgramID = createRectangleShader();

    // 3. Calculate ModelViewProjection Matrix
    VuMatrix44F modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    VuMatrix44F scaledModelViewMatrix;

    // Adjust scale and position as needed
    VuVector3F scaleVec{0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f};
    VuVector3F positionVec{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

    scaledModelViewMatrix = vuMatrix44FScale(scaleVec, modelViewMatrix);
    scaledModelViewMatrix = vuMatrix44FTranslate(positionVec, scaledModelViewMatrix);
    modelViewProjectionMatrix = vuMatrix44FMultiplyMatrix(projectionMatrix, scaledModelViewMatrix);

    // 4. Enable Blending and Disable Depth Test
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // 5. Use Shader Program and Set Attributes
    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    GLint vertexPositionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "a_Position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, rectVertices);

    // Texture Coordinate Attribute
    GLint textureCoordHandle = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, "a_TexCoord");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureCoords);

    // MVP Matrix Uniform
    GLint mvpMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "u_MVPMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)modelViewProjectionMatrix.data);

    // Texture Sampler Uniform
    GLint textureSamplerHandle = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "u_Texture");
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glUniform1i(textureSamplerHandle, 0); // Texture unit 0

    GLint colorHandle = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "u_Color");
    VuVector4F rectColor{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f}; // Green color
    glUniform4f(colorHandle, rectColor.data[0], rectColor.data[1], rectColor.data[2], rectColor.data[3]);

    // 6. Draw Rectangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    // 7. Disable Attributes and Shader Program
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionHandle);
    glUseProgram(0);

    // 8. Restore GL States (if needed)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}

renderImageTarget method :
void
GLESRenderer::renderImageTarget(VuMatrix44F &projectionMatrix, VuMatrix44F &modelViewMatrix,
                                VuMatrix44F &scaledModelViewMatrix,const char *target){

    VuMatrix44F scaledModelViewProjectionMatrix = vuMatrix44FMultiplyMatrix(
                    projectionMatrix,scaledModelViewMatrix );

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    float stateLineWidth;
    glGetFloatv(GL_LINE_WIDTH, &stateLineWidth);

    glUseProgram(mUniformColorShaderProgramID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(mUniformColorVertexPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (const GLvoid*)&squareVertices[0]);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mUniformColorVertexPositionHandle);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mUniformColorMvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, &scaledModelViewProjectionMatrix.data[0]);

    // Draw translucent solid overlay
    // Color RGBA
    glUniform4f(mUniformColorColorHandle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_SQUARE_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)&squareIndices[0]);

    // Draw solid outline
    glUniform4f(mUniformColorColorHandle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(4.0f);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, NUM_SQUARE_WIREFRAME_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)&squareWireframeIndices[0]);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(mUniformColorVertexPositionHandle);

    GLESUtils::checkGlError("Render Image Target");

    glLineWidth(stateLineWidth);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if(target != nullptr){
        if (strcasecmp(target, "ref") == 0){
            renderRectangle(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, mRefDeviceLayoutTextureUnit);
        } else {
            renderRectangle(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, mOvenDeviceLayoutTextureUnit);
        }
    }

}

renderFrame method:
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_smartboom_arengine_flutter_1smartboom_1ar_1engine_engine_vuforia_VuforiaARView_renderFrame(JNIEnv* /* env */, jobject /* this */)
{
    if (!controller.isARStarted())
    {
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    // Clear colour and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    int vbTextureUnit = 0;
    VuRenderVideoBackgroundData renderVideoBackgroundData;
    renderVideoBackgroundData.renderData = nullptr;
    renderVideoBackgroundData.textureData = nullptr;
    renderVideoBackgroundData.textureUnitData = &vbTextureUnit;
    double viewport[6];
    if (controller.prepareToRender(viewport, &renderVideoBackgroundData))
    {
        // Set viewport for current view
        glViewport(viewport[0], viewport[1], viewport[2], viewport[3]);

        auto renderState = controller.getRenderState();

        gWrapperData.renderer.renderVideoBackground(
                renderState.vbProjectionMatrix, renderState.vbMesh->pos, renderState.vbMesh->tex,
                renderState.vbMesh->numFaces, renderState.vbMesh->faceIndices, vbTextureUnit);

      /// for render world position that will be choose as engine configuration from flutter side
//      VuMatrix44F worldOriginProjection;
//      VuMatrix44F worldOriginModelView;
//      if (controller.getOrigin(worldOriginProjection, worldOriginModelView))
//      {
//          gWrapperData.renderer.renderWorldOrigin(worldOriginProjection, worldOriginModelView);
//      }

        VuMatrix44F trackableProjection;
        VuMatrix44F trackableModelView;
        VuMatrix44F trackableModelViewScaled;
//        VuImageInfo modelTargetGuideViewImage;
//        VuBool guideViewImageHasChanged;

        const char* resultTarget = controller.getImageTargetResult(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, trackableModelViewScaled);
        gWrapperData.renderer.renderImageTarget(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, trackableModelViewScaled,resultTarget);

//        if (controller.getModelTargetResult(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, trackableModelViewScaled))
//        {
//            gWrapperData.renderer.renderModelTarget(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, trackableModelViewScaled);
//        }
//        else if (controller.getModelTargetGuideView(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, modelTargetGuideViewImage,
//                                                    guideViewImageHasChanged))
//        {
//            gWrapperData.renderer.renderModelTargetGuideView(trackableProjection, trackableModelView, modelTargetGuideViewImage,
//                                                             guideViewImageHasChanged);
//        }

        if (gWrapperData.usingARCore)
        {
            accessFusionProviderPointers();
        }
    }
    controller.finishRender();
    return JNI_TRUE;
}


It could be that Engine only tracks one target at a time, as a default. I don't know about VUforia Engine SDK integration with Flutter, but you can set the number of simultaneous tracked images with the Engine API.
vuEngineSetMaximumSimultaneousTrackedImages(VuEngine* engine, int32_t maxNumberOfTargets);

Just note that only image-based targets support simultaneous tracking. Model Targets and Area Targets can only be tracked one at a time. This article has more information: Detect and track targets simultaenously.

Thanks for your response, but this line of the code is for set maximum number of tracking times which vuforia engine can doing and not worked in my case. also my requirement is not to tracking multiple image target simultaneously, in my scenario when I tracking second image target, first rendered model hide. I tracking image targets sequentially not concurrently. also I need every rendered target remain on its position and don't hide

Hi Ali, if Vuforia Engine finds a new target to track, it stops tracking and rendering content on other targets. You need to let Vuforia track multiple targets simultaneously by increasing the max simultaneous tracked images via the API that I posted to have the content of both ImageTarget1 and ImageTarget2 present. Hope it helps.
